# Why is there a large increase in volume when an alkali metal is dissolved in liquid ammonia?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, solutions, alkali-metals

My teacher said unexplainedly that when alkali metals dissolves in liquid ammonia, there is a large increase in the volume. I found a paper that confirms this fact [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01624a022)]:

> In the course of recent research it was necessary to obtain the volume change associated with the solution of lithium, sodium and potassium in liquid ammonia.
> That the solution of these metals in liquid ammonia is accompanied by a relatively large increase in volume has long been known.
> From the densities of sodium and potassium solutions it has been shown that these volume changes pass through a maximum at about $3N.$

I am still unaware of the reason for the increase of final volume $V_\mathrm{f}$ after reaction between metal $\ce{M}$ and liquid ammonia $\ce{NH3}$:

$$V_\mathrm{f} \gg V_0(\ce{M}) + V_0(\ce{NH3})$$

#### Reference

1. Marshall, P.; Hunt, H. Volume Changes for Metal Solutions in Liquid Ammonia. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1955**, 77 (19), 5016–5016. DOI: [10.1021/ja01624a022](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01624a022).

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72264/what-is-happening-in-this-video-of-solvated-electrons-donated-from-sodium-in-amm

Comment: Volume *always* changes when you dissolve something, what's the point of this question?

Comment: Rather just > than >>, as the latter implies formation of gaseous phase.

Comment: i just meant a large increase in volume i don't know if a gaseous phase is formed or not,maybe something is linked to gaseous phase for the increase.

Comment: Excellent question.  One reason I can think of is that the packing of atoms in solid alkali metals is pretty dense.  When dissolved in ammonia, this packing is undone, creating a solvated alkali metal cation and a solvated "electron".  Each of these solvated ions, consisting of shells of ammonia molecules presumably takes up a bunch of space.

Comment: @CurtF. If i consider only ammonia for an instance, then i am just adding a metal cation and a electron in between which also creates dipole-dipole attractions and is kind of filling voids present in solution so i think there should be a slight decrease or atleast not a large increase.